# How to configure common data model across android and JS bridge?

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, typescript, web

I have a JS bridge in Android,

```
public class WebInterface {
    Context mContext;
    public WebInterface(Context c) { this.mContext = c;}

    @JavascriptInterface
    public void showAlert() {
         Toast.makeText(mContext, "This is being called from the interface", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

I can set interface in my `webView`,

```
mWebView.addJavascriptInterface(WebInterface(this), "android");
```

This works fine for simple methods like `showAlert()` where the is no params when the params or the param is a simple string but when I need to pass a data model as a params while calling native functions from web app how can I bind data models? I am required to call implement a function with param of type custom data model.

```
public class WebInterface {
    Context mContext;
    public WebInterface(Context c) { this.mContext = c;}

    @JavascriptInterface
    public void showAlert() {
       Toast.makeText(mContext, "This is being called from the interface", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    public void saveData(data: DataModel) { // DataModel is custom model
       Toast.makeText(mContext, "Saving data model", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

How can I bind data model across native and web app. Is it possible using TypeScript? If so, how to configure? Is it only possible using plain json string as params? no any other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the JSON string.
You can create another function receive the format you want, then JSON.stringify the object before pass to the function.

Javascript

```
function saveData(obj){
  const json = JSON.stringify(obj);
  Android.saveData(json);
}
```

Comment: json string is one possible way. is there any other way?

Answer (score 0):

Alternative away is used to JSON.parse(data)

javascript

```
function loadJson(obj) {
  var jsonValue = JSON.parse(obj)
  Android.saveData(jsonValue)
}
```